# Using type predicates does not return the right type in TypScript 4.7.3

Tags: typescript

In the following example, I am using a user-defined type guard function in order to filter an array. I want a strongly typed array of only `Fish`.

The type are properly returned here, please note I am using a point free style:

```
const onlyFish = animals.filter(isFish); // Fish[]
```

The type are not properly returned here, It is a mixed array:

```
const onlyFish2 = animals.filter(x => isFish(x)); // (Fish | Bird)[]
```

- Why there is this different?
- How do you ensure the types are properly returned in onlyFish2 without doing `const onlyFish2: Fish[]`

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=69&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgZwBZQLxQN4Cgq6gNwEMAnOQgO2AC4oByAM0SVqwF8stRIoAhOYgCZpMOPEVIVqdAEb8BLdlgDGAe3IJgURPGTCAFBTgBbQgBsaOlAB9ecgJQ1DJ01oSwmaAHxQnZgHTiZJRoqOgMTLQA3Byq6pq%20pgg0AEoQhAJqpiAAgsTEhCAAPJZQNnyC3ugA2hgEJEFS4ci0UKwANJh1EpQ0tLKCLawAutHKahpQmSAl6AkIfoymwBDEetpMdpFQAPTb7shVQzHjmlOWAEzCcwtwSyt6AB5erpaPdps7e3olZfaHQA)

```
    type Fish = {
        variant: 'fish'
    }
    
    type Bird = {
        variant: 'bird'
    }
    
    const isFish = (animal: Fish | Bird): animal is Fish => animal.variant === 'fish';
    
    const animals: ReadonlyArray<Fish | Bird> = [{ variant: 'fish' }, { variant: 'bird' }];
    
    const onlyFish = animals.filter(isFish); // Fish[]
    
    const onlyFish2 = animals.filter(x => isFish(x)); // (Fish | Bird)[]
```

Comment: change `x => isFish` to just `isFish`. The anonymous arrow function you pass into filter does not have a type predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the following:

```js
const onlyFish = animals.filter(isFish);
```

Here, the result of the predicate will be `x is Fish` and as such TypeScript can correctly deduce the type.

However, in this case:

```js
const onlyFish2 = animals.filter(x => isFish(x));
```

The return value of your predicate is a `boolean` as you are returning the result from your type guard: *"is x a Fish?"*.